# Deny access to a specific folder for a sudo user

Tags: linux, unix, permissions, sudo

So here is the case: I am root in an Ubuntu system. I want to give a user (say username is X) permission to execute any command but at the same time I have a folder that I want no one to be able to access except my user (which is certainly not X because it is say Admin) or root. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: If the user is a superuser which can change the permissions and ownership of any file or folder you will find this extremely difficult to accomplish.  Does this user have to be a root/sudo user?